# How can I solve the following error: NameError: undefined local variable or method `email' for #<AuthenticateUser>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement JWT on my Rails API app. Before directly trying to modify my main project I was trying out a dummy project using [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api) *PluralSight* blog.

I followed all the steps mentioned in that tutorial/blog. But this error keeps showing up:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `email' for #<AuthenticateUser:0x684ca38>>",
"traces": {
    "Application Trace": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "trace": "app/commands/authenticate_user.rb:16:in `user'"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "trace": "app/commands/authenticate_user.rb:10:in `call'"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "trace": "app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb:7:in `authenticate'"
        }
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this error better? Like why this is occurring?  How do I debug this?
This is my second week using rails so please explain your solution & gimme some insider approach on how to solve this kinds of errors.

`App/commands/AuthenticateUser`  class:

```
class AuthenticateUser
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(email, password)
    @email = email
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
  end

  private

  def user
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticate(password)

    errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end
end
```

`App/controllers/authentication_controller.rb` class:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_request

  def authenticate
    au=AuthenticateUser.new(params[:email], params[:password])
    command = au.call()
    if command.success?
      render json: { auth_token: command.result }
    else
      render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized 
    end
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170814062006) do

  create_table "items", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
t.string "name"
t.text "description"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.string "email"
        t.string "password_digest"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <NameError: undefined local variable or method `email' for #<AuthenticateUser:0x684ca38>>"

As per that blog, you are missing `attr_accessor :email, :password` which resulted in that error. Try adding it in `AuthenticateUser`

```
class AuthenticateUser
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(email, password)
    @email = email
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :email, :password #here

  def user
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticate(password)

    errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: can you please explain what it does?

Comment: @irdalin Have a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor